# No imprime los vectores en C

Tags: c

El programa almacena el número de productos, sus nombres y sus precios.

Cuando trato de imprimirlos, es decir, que muestre los datos previamente insertados, no muestra nada.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    int opcion,opcion2;
    char producto[100];
    float precio[100];
    int n,i;

    
    printf("\n1)Ingresar producto");
    printf("\n2)Salir: ");
    printf("\nElija la opción: ");
    scanf("%d", &opcion);
    if(opcion==2){
        printf("\nNo hay productos");
        printf("\n");
        while(opcion!=1){
            printf("\n1)Ingresar producto");
            printf("\n2)Salir: ");
            printf("\nElija la opción: ");
            scanf("%d", &opcion);
        }
    }
    
    printf("Número de productos: ");
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("\n Ingrese el producto: ");
        scanf("%s", &producto[i]);
        printf("\n Ingrese el precio: ");
        scanf("%f", &precio[i]);
    }
    
    printf ("Producto Precio\t\n");
    printf ("----------------------------------------------\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%s    %.2f", producto[i], precio[i]);
    }   
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para almacenar un string necesitas un array:

```
char producto[100];
```

Y para almacenar `n` strings, necesitas `n` arrays:

```
char producto[n][100];
```

El resto del código puedes dejarlo como lo tienes

Ahora bien, dado que `n` es una variable, la capacidad de `producto` dependerá de un valor variable. Esto se conoce como "Variable Length Array" o VLA y es una característica **no soportada** por el estándar, lo que quiere decir que dependerá del compilador que te funcione.

La opción conforme al estándar sería usar memoria dinámica:

```
char **producto = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    producto[i] = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
```

Esta sería la forma *legal* de crear un array de `n` strings

Answer (score 0):

En una variable de tipo `char` solo puedes almacenar un carácter.

Para almacenar un nombre necesitarás varios carácteres.

Tal como lo tienes ahora, intuyo que deseas poder almacenar hasta 100 elementos.

100 caracteres / 100 elementos = 1 carácter por elemento.

Lo que puedes hacer es elegir un número de caracteres máximo para todas las palabras y multiplicarlo por 100.

Supongamos que quieres un máximo de 25 caracteres. 25*100 = 2500

Adaptando tu código, acabarías con algo así:

```
char productos[2500];

...

for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("\n Ingrese el producto: ");
    scanf("%25s", &productos[25 * i])
    ...
}

...

for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("%25s    %.2f", &productos[25 * i], precio[i]);
}   

...
```