# ¿Cómo guardo los datos de un vector una vez que regresé a una función en C++?

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema con un programa que estoy haciendo, pues me pide que con una función de de alta restaurantes y los añada a un vector de tamaño [100]. El problema es que al momento de dar de alta los restaurantes y querer volver al menú principal.

```
void altas(){
    //variables
    char nombre;
    int res, cantidad;

    //Antes de pedir dar de alta un restaurante especificar cuantos restuarantes se van a dar de alta para limitar el bucle
    cout<<"¿Cuantos restaurantes deseas añadir a la lista?"<<endl;
    cin>>cantidad;

    //Ciclo para añadir valores
    for(int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
    cout<<"Ingresa el nombre del restaurante en la posición ["<<i<<"]: "<<endl;
    cin>>restaurantes[nombre];
    }
    menu(); //Función que se activa una vez que termina el ciclo y te regresa al menú principal
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [No imprime los vectores en C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/532296/169744) En caso contrario, siendo que estás en C++, considera usar lo que la librería estándar te brinda, [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) para arreglos y [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) para conjuntos de caracteres.

Comment: ¿Dónde y cómo tienes definida la variable `restaurantes`?

Comment: El vector restaurantes está escrito fuera del main y de las demás funciones que estoy escribiendo. Lo tengo como un vector de tipo string de 100 espacios. @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: Si `restaurantes`está declarado como una variable global, puedes acceder a su contenido desde cualquier parte del archivo en que lo declaras.